# An example of a group with $1+np$ Sylow $p$-subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to find an example of a group $G$ with $1+p$ Sylow $p$-subgroups, where $p$ is a fixed prime. My problem is I don't know a lot of known Sylow subgroups, and the answer of this depends on $p$.

Then I'd like to know if this can be done easily for $1+np$.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: In my post 2 days ago I gave many examples and answering your question completely. So consider accepting or rejecting it, instead of doing nothing about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $p=2$, the Klein's group $\{1,3,5,7\}$ (mod 8 multiplication) has
3 subgroups (they are the only proper subgroups).

For $p=3$, and $p=5$, the examples are $S_4$ and $S_5$ respectively.